# Convert a SELECT column to Date in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, type-conversion

I have this SQL query is MySql, not working:

```
select email, cast(select tag from user_tags where userid=users.id limit 1,date) as date
from users
```

The error is: "select" is not valid at this position for this server version, and it highlights the **select** right after cast.

Comment: You are casting whole select stmt which you can't

Comment: If you are looking for a specific tag eg first or last then and order by...limit would be appropriate,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast a column but not a whole query. So consider using

```sql
SELECT email, 
       (SELECT CAST(tag AS DATE) FROM user_tags WHERE userid=u.id LIMIT 1) AS date
  FROM users AS u
```

as a correlated subquery containing a column with type conversion

Answer (score 1):

You can cast an expression not a statement.

```
select email, cast((select tag from user_tags where userid=users.id limit 1) as date) as date
from users
```